# Averaging replicate data in Matlab, multiple variables

Tags: matlab, accumarray

I'm trying to average replicate data in MATLAB and running into some difficulty. The variables are `depth`, `Var1`, `Var2`. Sometimes there is a replicate in `Var1`, sometimes there is a replicate in `Var2`, sometimes there is a replicate for both `Var1` and `Var2` for a given `depth`. So the matrix might look something like this:

```
1   0.2 1,
2   0.5 3,
2   0.7 NaN,
3   0.1 5,
3   0.7 6,
4   0.3 4,
...
```

`depth` is the unique identifier so I would like to create a matrix with `[depth, Var1, Var2]` that looks like this:

```
1   0.2 1,
2   0.6 3,
3   0.4 5.5,
4   0.3 4,
...
```

The function `accumarray` would work if I had an n-by-2 matrix, but this is n-by-3. Any recommendations on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
a=[1 0.2 1; 2 0.5 3; 2 0.7 NaN; 3 0.1 5; 3 0.7 6; 4 0.3 4];
depths = unique(a(:,1));
b=nan(length(depths),3);
for ct = 1:length(depths)
    b(ct,:)=mean(a(a(:,1)==depths(ct),:),1,'omitnan');
end
```

result

```
b =

    1.0000    0.2000    1.0000
    2.0000    0.6000    3.0000
    3.0000    0.4000    5.5000
    4.0000    0.3000    4.0000
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

A bit naive implementation with `accumarray` which loops over the variables.

```
A = [1   0.2 1
2   0.5 3
2   0.7 NaN
3   0.1 5
3   0.7 6
4   0.3 4];

result = zeros([numel(unique(A(:,1))) size(A,2)]);
result(:,1) = unique(A(:,1));
for ii = 2:size(A,2)
    result(:,ii) = accumarray(A(:,1),A(:,ii),[],@mean);
end
```